# Get value from list of links using the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links and these links have a unique data-value="1" or data-value="2" or something else and the same class="create_post".

```
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="3">Link 3</a>
```

When the link is clicked it fires a JS script.

```
$('.create_post').click(function(event){
    var com = $('.create_post').data('value');     
});
```

This works great but the com returs "1" from the first value of the list and not from the link that is clicked.

I have tried **$(this).attr('value');** but that does not return anything.
I have tried using id="create_post" but with the same result.

How do I get the data-value from the actual link that is clicked?

Comment: `var com = $(this).data('value');  `

Comment: Use $(this) instead of $('.create_post')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `this` within the click handler to reference the element that raised the event. Your current code is retrieving `data()` from the collection, and as it can only return one value, it gets the attribute from the first element only.

Try this:

```js
$('.create_post').click(function(event) {
  var com = $(this).data('value');
  console.log(com);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="3">Link 3</a>
```

Also note that your use of `attr()` didn't work as it should be `attr('data-value')`, but it should be noted that using the `data()` method is better practice where possible.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `this` in the event handler.

```
var com = $(this).data('value');
```

```js
$('.create_post').click(function(event) {
  var com = $(this).data('value');
  console.log(com);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="3">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.create_post').click(function(event) {
  var com = $(this).data('value');
  alert(com)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="create_post" data-value="3">Link 3</a>
```

We must use `this` inside the click handler to address the element that raised the event.